# React 'this' undefined when adding table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm attempting to add a new row of data to a table that occurs when a user inputs text into a field and clicks a button. 
The button click is tied to a function (AddNewRow) which sends the data to a controller and then adds a new row to the table with the data.

The data is sent to the controller correctly and if the page is refreshed the new row is showing (because of the get request after mount) but the problem is the table doesn't update dynamically.

I keep getting a console error saying 'this is undefined' in the AddNewRow function. 
Ive attempted to bind 'this' to the constructor by using both `'.bind(this)'` and `AddNewRow() => {}` but it still doesn't bind?

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        tableData: [{            
        }],         
    };       
  }  

   componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/Jobs/GetJobs', {
        responseType: 'json'
    }).then(response => {        
        this.setState({ tableData: response });
    });
}

AddNewRow(){

    axios.post('/Controller/CreateJob', { Name: this.refs.NewJobName.value})
        .then(function (response){               
            if(response.data.Error) {                   
                window.alert(response);
            }
        else {
                var data = this.setState.tableData;
                this.setState.tableData.push(response);
                this.setState({ tableData: data });
            }
        })}

    render() {
    const { tableData } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.AddNewRow()} >ADD</button>
        <input ref="NewJobName" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        <ReactTable 
        data={tableData}
         /> 
        </div>
       )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function to make `this` available in the `then` function:

```
axios
  .post('/Controller/CreateJob', { Name: this.refs.NewJobName.value })
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.data.Error) {
      window.alert(response);
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ 
        tableData: prevState.tableData.concat([response]) 
      }));
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hmm ok thats fixed the 'this' issue but now its telling me "this.setState.tableData is undefined" ?

Comment: You probably meant to access `this.state.tableData`, but you shouldn't mutate your state directly anyway. See my updated code.

Comment: Ah I havn't used 'prevState' before. Thanks, thats great, I appreciate the help!