# React Js Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am learning to react, facing this issue while making the ajax request, even I'm getting the response but not able pass that response to other function { this.showBattersData(data); } where I can render the dom. this is pretty obvious that I'm missing something here. any help will be appreciated.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { fetchFactory } from '../Fetch/fetchFactory'
    
    var batters = [];
    var rowdata = "";

    
export class Body extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.battersDataFetchReq = this.battersDataFetchReq.bind(this);
        this.showBattersData = this.showBattersData.bind(this);
        this.battersDataFetchReq();
    }    

    //ajax request
    battersDataFetchReq() {
        fetchFactory('./assets/some.json', 'GET')
        .then(function(data) {
            //this.showBattersData = this.showBattersData.bind(this);
            this.showBattersData(data); // this is where i'm getting this error

        })
    }

    showBattersData(res) {
        console.log("inside showBattersData:: ", res);
        rowdata = `
            <table id="batters" name="batters" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <caption>List of batters</caption>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <tbody id="batters_body">`;    
        batters = res.batters.batter;
        for(var i = 0; i < batters.length; i++) {
            rowdata += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${[i + 1]}</td>
                    <td>${batters[i].id}</td>
                    <td>${batters[i].type}</td>
                </tr>`;
        }
        rowdata += `</tbody></table>`;
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {rowdata}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284049/react-this-undefined-when-adding-table-row/50284079#50284079

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React 'this' undefined when adding table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284049/react-this-undefined-when-adding-table-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to `Context` concept in `JavaScript`.

In JS `function`s have their Context and that means `this` keyword refer to the function itself.

You can use one of 2 following solutions:

One:

```
battersDataFetchReq() {
    let self = this;

    fetchFactory('./assets/some.json', 'GET')
        .then(function (data) {            
            self.showBattersData(data);    
        })
}
```

Tow (aka `Arrow function`): *recommended solution*

```
battersDataFetchReq() {
    fetchFactory('./assets/some.json', 'GET')
        .then((data) => {
            this.showBattersData(data);
        })
}
```

Wondering why? From MDN:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this.

Continue reading ... (*both links are from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)*)

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thanks, @Mehdi Dehghani for your time, with arrow function its working fine, the only issue is inside render() function the rowdata coming as blank but when console it from showBattersData(), it has all the data, any solution.

Comment: React re-render when state changes, so maybe you should try to change state when ajax req is done. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39066972/3367974 and https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.bind(this)` your request callback or use an arrow function:

```
//ajax request
battersDataFetchReq() {
    fetchFactory('./assets/some.json', 'GET')
    .then((data) => { // Here, use a lambda or this will not point to your class
        this.showBattersData(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: you mean to say arrow functions () => ?